# error TS2345: Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to paramete r of type 'string | IScheduler'

Tags: angular, ngrx

here is my code:

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/interval";
import "rxjs/add/observable/merge";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/startWith";
import "rxjs/add/operator/scan";
import "rxjs/add/operator/mapTo";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <button (click)="click$.next()">Update</button>
    <h1>{{clock | async | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</h1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  click$ = new Subject<any>();
  clock;

  constructor() {
    this.clock = Observable.merge(
      this.click$.mapTo('hour'),
      Observable.interval(1000).mapTo('second')
    )
      .startWith(new Date())
      .scan((acc: Date, curr) => {
        const date: Date = new Date(acc.getTime());
        if (curr === 'hour') {
          date.setHours(date.getHours() + 1);
        }
        if (curr === 'second') {
          date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 1);
        }
        return date;
      });
  }
}
```

I got this error on startWith(**new Date()**),but when I change "this.click$.mapTo('hour')" to "this.click$",this error is gone.
Can anyone tell what went wrong?

Comment: Are you looking for `startsWith` not `startWith`?

Answer (score 0):

`Observable.merge` turn multiple observables into a single observable. when you are using following code return type is `Observable<any,string>`

```
  this.clock = Observable.merge(
              this.click$,
              Observable.interval(1000).mapTo('second')
            )
```

but when you are using following code snippet the return type is `Observable<string,string>` so that `scan` operator is accepting string as first argument and giving the error

```
this.clock = Observable.merge(
      this.click$.mapTo('hour'),
      Observable.interval(1000).mapTo('second')
    )
```